# 'Lost connection to device.' in android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, webview, web-applications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkEK0.png)
hello. I am opening a webview using Flutter in Android Studio.
I am making a flutter page because I need a settings page before opening the webview.
A message appears and the device disconnects.
There are no errors. Has anyone ever solved it? When connected it works fine.

I've tried everything I could, including cleaning flutter and clearing the cache, and reinstalling the emulator. But it doesn't work.